# How to add a server runtime to multiple existing projects in Eclipse (Kepler with Oracle tools) at once

Tags: java, eclipse, server, runtime

I know how to add a server runtime to one existing project. Is there a way to add the same server runtime to (45 in my case) existing projects at once? Just looking to space myself the hassle of adding each one individually.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah it's possible, just make sure that the projects you have all have compatible configurations with the single server runtime.

If you're on Eclipse, it's just a matter of right clicking the project, click 'Run As' > 'Run On Server' > then choose the server that is currently running. You will see an error message if the configurations do not match.

Comment: mark as answer if it answers your question :) 

gave your post an up-vote.

Comment: Thanks! Eclipse is smarter than I thought